# Translating rows in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

Is there a non-cost option for translating a data frame into another language? For example, if I have following data frame containing German strings:

```
df <- data.frame(words = c("Hallo", "Ampel", "Straße"))
```

How could I translate the data frame into English so that:

```
df$words
hello traffic-light street
```

Packages like `googleLanguageR` or `translateR` require the purchase of an API key. Are there any other APIs/R Packages I can use?

Any help is appreciated!